# Get XML-element using XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I need to process xml-file in a different way depending on *type* element.
I use `findnodes($xpath,$contextNode)` method to find elements that are part of one structure.
Elements can have two types `<type>A</type>` and `<type>B</type>`.
Is there any way, when I process node with type B to "jump" to element with type A in order to get ID-value?

Basically I need to be able to find out that
element with id 2 and type B is in the same structure as element with id 1 and type A.
Any ideas how can I jump in structure upwards?

```xml
<structure>
    <element>
        <def>
            <id>1</id>
            <type>A</type>
        </def>
    </element>
    <element>
        <def>
            <id>2</id>
            <type>B</type>
        </def>
    </element>
</structure>
```

Comment: What do you mean with “is in the same structure”?

Comment: they are both part of the <structure> element

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parent` axis.

```perl
my ( $elementB ) = $xpc->findnodes(
   "parent::*/element[ def/type='B' ]",
   $elementA,
);
```

[Demo](http://xpather.com/u4gSK3Ka) on xpather.com<sup>[1]</sup>

---

XPath provides the convenient `..` shortcut.

```perl
my ( $elementB ) = $xpc->findnodes(
   "../element[ def/type='B' ]",
   $elementA,
);
```

[Demo](http://xpather.com/XVgQMYiO) on xpather.com<sup>[1]</sup>

---

Alternatively, you can use a combination of the `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` axes.

```perl
my ( $elementB ) = $xpc->findnodes(
   " preceding-sibling::*[ def/type='B' ]
   | following-sibling::*[ def/type='B' ]
   ",
   $elementA,
);
```

[Demo](http://xpather.com/CjKNC4Jr) on xpather.com<sup>[1]</sup>

---

Outside of XPath, `$node->parentNode` will get the parent node. This answer focused on XPath since the OP mentioned `findnodes`, and because it's terser and simpler.

---

1. I think this supports XPath 2, while libxml2 (used by XML::LibXML) only supports XPath 1, but these paths should be valid for both.

Comment: Fixed problems.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have tested your example with sibling. The problem is my "parent" ($elementB) is <def> and not <element>, because I need to define it like "root_node". Then I found element with type A and should check if under <structure> is any <def> with type B. Something like this:
(/root/structure/element/def[ type='A' ])[1]/(
preceding-sibling::*[ element/def/type='B' ]

Comment: So you want the siblings of the parent

Comment: yes, my current position is <def> and I want to "jump" to <def> of type B.

Comment: It wasn't a question.